# Introducing variables into a python function namespace

Tags: python, scope

Let's say that I am trying to build a model object `m`.
I would like to attach some variables and equations to `m`, so I have:

```
class ModelBuilder():
  def build_model():
    m = MyModel()
    self.add_variables(m)
    self.add_equations(m)
    if self.feeling_good:
      self.add_other_equations_sometimes(m)
    return m

  def add_variables(self, m):
    m.a = MyVar(domain=Reals)
    m.b = MyVar()
    m.c = MyVar()
    ...

  def add_equations(self, m):
    m.pythagoras = MyEqn(expression=m.a ** 2 + m.b ** 2 == m.c ** 2)
    ...

  def add_other_equations_sometimes(self, m):
    m.eqnname = MyEqn(expression=m.a + m.b == m.c)
    ...
```

This works. But let's say that I have quite a few variables and some complicated equations where I would rather not have to write `m.<name>` for everything in the expressions. I would rather have `a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c ** 2` to look at.

I can do this if I put everything in one function and have:

```
  def add_modelthings(self, m):
    a = m.a = MyVar(domain=Reals)
    b = m.b = MyVar()
    c = m.c = MyVar()
    ...
    m.pythagoras = MyEqn(expression=a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c ** 2)
    ...
    if self.feeling_good:
      m.eqnname = MyEqn(expression=a + b == c)
      ...
```

But then I have a really cluttered function for a large model. It is tempting to use locals() or globals():

```
class ModelBuilder():
  def build_model():
    m = MyModel()
    var_dict = self.add_variables(m)
    self.add_equations(m, var_dict)
    if self.feeling_good:
      self.add_other_equations_sometimes(m, var_dict)
    return m

  def add_variables(self, m):
    a = m.a = MyVar(domain=Reals)
    b = m.b = MyVar()
    c = m.c = MyVar()
    ...
    return locals()

  def add_equations(self, m, var_dict):
    locals().update(var_dict)
    m.pythagoras = MyEqn(expression=a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c ** 2)
    ...

  def add_other_equations_sometimes(self, m, var_dict):
    locals().update(var_dict)
    m.eqnname = MyEqn(expression=a + b == c)
    ...
```

But after reading all the warnings about updating locals() and being wary that globals() updates variable values across the whole module and not just the class, I am not sure what the best way is to accomplish this simplicity in the variables for my mathematical expressions.

Comment: Perhaps you could pass expressions as strings (e.g. `"a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c ** 2`) and the variables in a dictionary, then pass both to `eval` at some appropriate place? It's not really clear to me what your `ModelBuilder` class is or how it relates to `MyModel` (especially since most of the methods you show don't take `self` as an argument).

Comment: Forgot to add that `self` argument in the functions when I was making the example. MyModel is actually a ConcreteModel object from the Pyomo library, if that helps.